# jQuery gMap 2 - Adding html to content: line

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml, jquery-gmap3

I'm using gMap on a site I'm finishing off and as an example from the gMap site I am using the following method;

```
    $('#map').gMap('addMarker',
    {
        latitude: 0,
        longitude: 0,
        content: 'Some HTML content'
    }
);
```

In the content: 'some HTML content' line I have added a line of html including an img and a div of text. Like this'

```
content: '<img src="img/shop.jpg" alt="shopfront" /><div id="map-text"><h2>Elan Hair Design</h2><p>17 Woodgate, Rothley,<br />Leicestershire. XXXXXXX</p><h3>T: XXXXXXXXX</h3></div>'
```

It all looks and works great, but when I validate under xhtml strict I get errors about adding a img and div tag in the content: '' line.

Have I mis-understood the type of html that can be added to this area? Or have I just done it wrong.

Any help would be greatly received.

Wayne

Comment: Are you using CDATA around your javascript ?

Comment: No. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have javascript in an XHTML document the correct way to embedded it is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
// content of your Javascript goes here
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

see [**here**](http://javascript.about.com/library/blxhtml.htm) for an explanation.